# Perl regex - store reference to regex captures in a variable

Tags: regex, perl, variables

Just wondering if/how this would work:

```
my $capture = qr/perl pattern( is.*)/; 
my $string = "perl pattern is complicated";
my $print_it = "Printing test: $1\n";

if($string =~ m/$capture/){
print $print_it; 
}
```

I've tried quoting $print_it in different ways (qw, qr, '', ""), but it is uninitialized when I create the pattern string and doesn't get set at runtime.

Other ways around, I'm sure, but this would be convenient.

EDIT:
Here's what I'm trying to accomplish. I want the user to provide an argument to define how to format the input string. Like, --format 1
Input string:
"user=username Resources_used_cput=20:00:01 Resources_used_walltime=10:00"
Say I want to pull just the walltime or cputime and username based on a flag from the command line. I was thinking about defining sets of formatting options like 0 for username only, 1 for username and cputime, 2 for username and walltime. With 3 it's easy to do with brute force, and just define some if/then statements or cases for the match. As that scales up I would prefer an array to a large list of if's/cases.

```
$formats = (
qr/user=(\S+)/,
qr/user=(\S+).*Resources_used_cput=(\d+):(\d+):(\d+)/,
qr/user=(\S+).*Resources_used_walltime=(\d+):(\d+)/);
# These are wrong for reasons stated in answers:
$responses = (
"username is $1",
"user $1 used $4 seconds, $3 minutes and $2 hours of cputime"
"user $1 used $2 hours $3 minutes of walltime");
```

vs

```
if(m/user=(\S+).*Resources_used_cput=(\d+):(\d+):(\d+).*Resources_used_walltime=(\d+):(\d+)/){
$user=$1;
$wall="$5:$6";
$cpu="$2:$3:$4";
}
if($format == 0){
print "username is $user"
}
elsif....
```

I'm guessing there's a better way?

Comment: `$1` is just a variable, and variables are expanded in strings when you do the assignment.

Comment: I don't think there's any way to create a string that expands its variables only when it's printed. Why don't you write a function that does what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn `$print_it` into a code reference.

```
my $print_it = sub { "Printing test: $1\n" };
...
print $print_it->();  # or print &$print_it;
```

Comment: I could make an array of subroutine references which would fit what I'm trying to do nicely. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to quote $capture at all; see below.

```
my $capture = qr/perl pattern( is.*)/;
my $string = "perl pattern is complicated";
my $print_it = "Printing test: $1\n";

if($string =~ $capture){
   print $print_it;
   print "Printing test: $1\n";
}
```

But the problem is that $1 is evaluated inside the string on line 3, not later when you print it.  In the code above, the second "printing test" will work, but the first one won't.

```
Printing test: 
Printing test:  is complicated
```

Comment: This makes sense to me and confirms what I was suspecting was going on. I would love a suggestion, though.